# Manga where a town is cursed and is experiencing a drought for a long time

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember the town being cursed and the townsmen haven't seen or eaten fish in a long time. There are also dungeon-like monsters in the manga. In the end, the main character (a girl) has lifted the curse and it finally rained.

The manga is black and white but had some pages with color, specifically the monster illustration page. I remember reading a physical copy of it as a kid around 2010, but I lost it and can't remember its title.

Comment: https://www.anime-planet.com/forum/threads/can-someone-help-me-to-find-this-manga.340150/ possibly looking for the same manga

Comment: Can you put a year to when you read this as a kid?

Comment: around 2010 but i believe the book is a lot older than that probably from 2002